# Is Jaime supposed to be pronounced in the Spanish way?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I always thought Jaime Lannister was pronouned like High-me (replace the J with an H), since Jaime is the Spanish spelling, however on the TV show, his name is pronounced like Jamie.

Did GRRM simply want a different spelling of Jamie or did he intend for it to be pronounced like High-me?

Comment: Or maybe GRRM intended the Portuguese pronunciation?

Comment: I believe technically no matter what, it's pronounced the Westerosi way.

Answer (score 15):

The [Wikepedia page for George R R Martin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_R._R._Martin) contains the following information about his association with the Game Of Thrones TV series

> Martin serves as the series' co-executive producer, while also
>   scripting one of each season's 10 episodes.

so I think it is fairly sensible to assume that if the actors were pronouncing the name incorrectly that he would have told them so. Based on that alone I would say that we can infer that the pronunciation is the same as the for the English name "Jamie".

Not that this is unusual at all - the English actress Jaime Murray uses this spelling of her name and pronounces it as "Jamie".

I cannot provide a definitive quote that says that GRRM has decreed it is pronounced one way or another but based on the above, common sense would indicate that the TV series portrays things as they are meant to be in this regard and that the one-word answer to your question is "No".

Answer (score 3):

English standardised its spelling centuries later than other western European languages, and so there are many medieval variants of the 'same' name. GRRM [frequently borrows such spellings](https://youtu.be/nTBQZBMQtOw) for his westerosi characters to give a more authentic medieval England feel.

As such, it is fair to assume he intended a modern English pronunciation of "Jamie" for the spelling "Jaime", and Indeed this is how he pronounces it in interviews.

Note the pronunciation used in the show cannot always be used as a barometer for GRRM's intended pronunciation - many names are pronounced differently by GRRM e.g.

| Name | Show pronunciation | GRRM pronunciation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dothraki | /doθ'raki/ | /doθ'rakai/ |
| Balon | /'beilon/ | /'balon/ |

Answer (score -3):

Basing a persons name pronunciation on what an author thinks is correct is like basing what fruits are the best depending on what your local fruiterer says is best for you. In other words just because an author handles words and a fruiterer handles fruit & vegies does not give them any authority whatsoever.
In fact pronouncing Jaime as Jamie is wrong according to many professional sources on the net whose job it is to give us the correct pronunciation of words.

Comment: Cite such a source at the least

Comment: It's a fantasy setting. Real-world guidelines regarding word pronunciation do not apply. And names aren't beholden to the same standardization as words anyway.